# Java How to get date format : dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS” with Date variable

Tags: java, date

I wouldlike to change format of my date variable :

```
private java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
```

I use it to set Date in my database (postgresql) :

```
stmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime()));
```

How can I transform my actual format : dd/MM/yyyy to dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS ?

Comment: Date objects don't have a format, just a value.

Comment: `SimpleDateTImeFormatter` doesn't help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the hours, minutes and seconds, you have to use DateTime or LocalDateTime type instead of java.util.Date. Date only stores the year, month and day. 
Then, you can use a formatter. For example:

```
public DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS");
```

Comment: In PosgreSQL, you should use TIMESTAMP instead of DATETIME. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date utilDate = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS", Locale.US);
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(utilDate.getTime()));
    }
```

Output:

> 12/10/2020 19:45:50.552

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the column in your database that you are trying to set? `Date` or `Timestamp`?

You can find all datatypes supported by POSTGRESQL for `Date` and `Time` [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html)

And for java's implementation (or lack there of) of `DateTime` refer to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_date.asp)

Example of getting current Date and Time in java:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime; // Import the LocalDateTime class
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter; // Import the DateTimeFormatter class

public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime myDateObj = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println("Before formatting: " + myDateObj);
    DateTimeFormatter myFormatObj = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS");

    String formattedDate = myDateObj.format(myFormatObj);
    System.out.println("After formatting: " + formattedDate);
  }
}
```

Output:

> Before Formatting: 2020-10-12T13:43:05.553697 
> After Formatting: 12/10/2020 13:43:05.553